# Correct pin naming of BGA and DIL chips

Tags: packages, integrated-circuit

Some ICs have their pins labelled only with numerical values and some use alphanumeric labels. I want to know what is the correct naming term for these cases.

Is it ok to call all the chips with alphanumeric labels BGA (ball grid array)?  And for chips with only numeric pin labels the chip should be called DIL (dual in line)?

Comment: Lot's of people say DIP instead of DIL. I suppose this depends on where you are. Here in the US, it's DIP (Dual In-line Package).  However, that's a moot point since nobody uses DIP anymore anyway.  I can't even remember the last time we specified a DIP in a design.

Comment: Here in europe even the current flows differently :D my question is only BGA chips use alphanum pin naming?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Typically ICs with **pins on the edges** have numbered pins. That's DIL, but also QFP, DFN and even SOT23. You start at the pin 1 marker and follow the contour. IIRC PLCCs have their pin 1 in the middle of one of the sides, but normally pin 1 is one of the corners.

You'll see alphanumeric pin IDs whenever you've got some kind of **grid**, where there could be confusion about which are rows and which are columns. Usual suspects are BGA, PGA, and variants like WSP (WaferScale Packaging), but also this one:

[image: package]

One found this one recently, it's called a "Staggered Dual-row MicroLeadFrame® Package (MLF)". Like some BGAs where only the outer pins are used this one numbers the outer pins as "A*", and the next round as "B*".

Answer (score 5):

The naming of the pins cannot be used to determine the package type. As Bruno notes you have many different types of Dual In Line pacakges (packages with pins on two sides in a line)

You also have many quad packages (TQFP, PLCC, QFN, etc) which have pins in a line on all 4 sides, numbering from pin 1 corner anticlockwise.

Aside from BGAs with alphanumeric numbering you also have PGAs (pin grid arrays) and some other newer packages (that may be specific to one manufacturer), like the [Array LLP](http://www.national.com/packaging/mkt/lfa92a.pdf) which is a bit like a QFN with 2 rows:

[image: Array LLP]

The fact the pins are in an X*X array is not a complete guarantee of the numbering being alphanumeric though, there are some odd packages out there:

[image: IC example]

To get an idea of how many different package types there are out there, take a look at this [list of packages used by National](http://www.national.com/packaging/parts/ARRAYLLP.html).

Comment: What's the weirdo a package of?

Comment: @Steven - it's an [LTCC](http://www.national.com/packaging/folders/sb70a.html) package, used in an [LMX9838](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lmx9838.pdf) bluetooth IC.

Answer (score 2):

Usually only BGAs have alphanumeric pin naming.

Regarding numeric pin names ICs, not all are DIL, you also have QTFP, and other less common packages that use numerical pin naming.

For dual-in-line there are also many variants such as SOIC, MSOP, just to name a few.